# Why people still using angular 1.4 for new project?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I used to see many developper that keep using Angular 1.4 for **new project** whereas Angular 1.6 was released.
So the question is, is there any problem in those version that make developper want to keep using 1.4 ?

Comment: I'm still using Angular 1.3 in applications and Angular 1.5.8 in anothers... I can't just update my applications, i need to test them first. I can't trust 100% those new versions. Responsability. I've had problem with kind of update in past using jquery, knockout and other libraries.

Comment: Yep, welcome to version hell. If you have something that works, it's a whole lot less work to leave it where it is and not upgrade it. There are so many things that can break, and if you have a production environment the cost of retesting completely is huge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading a large system can be a costly procedure. There can be many types of issues involved most notably those related to compatibility and dependencies. This could be a reason for not upgrading existing applications. However, for building creating a new projects, it is advisable to go with latest stable versions to take the benefits of new features and enhancements.

Comment: Thanks, so there is no reason to begin a new project with Angular 1.4 rather than with Angular